# Creating a Outlook .MSG file in C#

Tags: c#, outlook

I've been tasked with writing a outlook .MSG files from XML files that have associated metadata. I've tried using the Aspose library, but all of the exposed MapiMessage properties are read only. Using the Outlook Object Model I'm unable to change the creation date, and other properties that I must have access to. I've also tried the Rebex library also, but it exports to EML, and doesn't support RTF.

My question is, is there a Mapi or any kind of way to write a .MSG file and have access over every property?

Comment: FWIW, Outlook Redemption might be able to support this with the "direct" (e.g. non-Safe*) classes it exposes. It will only work with some compute properties, however.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/
Not positive, but it sounds like it can do what you need

Answer (score 3):

Aspose now supports creating new msg files. Please check out http://www.aspose.com/documentation/utility-components/aspose.network-for-.net/creatingsaving-outlook-message-msg-files.html for details.

However, updating existing msg files is not supported currently. If you load an msg file using MapiMessage class, the properties will still be readonly.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use [RDOSession](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm).`CreateMessageFromMsgFile` in [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) (I am its author). You will get back [RDOMail](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOMail.htm) object; all you will need to do is set all the properties and call [RDOMail](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOMail.htm).Save.

Something along the lines of

```
  Redemption.RDOSession Session = new RDOSession();
  Redemption.RDOMail Msg = Session.CreateMessageFromMsgFile(@"c:\temp\YourMsgFile.msg");
  Msg.Sent = true;
  Msg.Subject = "test";
  Msg.Body = "test body";
  Msg.Recipients.AddEx("the user", "user@domain.demo", "SMTP", rdoMailRecipientType.olTo);
  Msg.Save();
```